# Make dock appear on both screens at the same time

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, display, dock

I have an external screen connected to my mac.

I have my Dock configured to be always displayed (not hiding it below the screen)

How do I make the Dock appear on both screens at the same time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell dock preferences
        properties
    end tell
end tell
```

This is everything supported natively:

```
{minimize effect:genie, magnification size:1.0, dock size:0.321428567171, 
autohide:false, animate:true, magnification:false, screen edge:bottom, 
class:dock preferences object}
```

Plus, as purely a philosophical question, the Dock can not be displayed on both screes at the same time.

Suppose you have one Dock per display. If you have cursor focus on display 1 (i.e. Menu Bar is not greyed/faded out), you move the cursor to display 2 with its greyed out Menu Bar and click on a Dock to launch a new app.

**Where should the new window go?** It should go to display 1 because display 1 has the focus. Yet it should also go to display because it's where the Dock that launched it is at.

Take a step back, there is another question. **What should happen when you click on Dock on an unfocused display?** Shouldn't focus be switch to the Dock/display before anything else? So launching an app is a double click process. Or more precisely, single-click if the display is in focus, double-click if not. And how do you tell if the Dock is in Focus? Move your eyes all the way up to Menu Bar (or Window Bar of frontmost window).

This is not an issue on other OS's. This mess can be trace back to when OS X compromised window focus long ago by place Menu Bar on top instead of in window. Not able to have multiple Docks is one small ramification of that design decision.

Comment: Agh, thanks for the explanation. This sucks. Ain't there any way to switch off the whole "first click is to focus" thing?

Comment: Not that I know. If hover is to focus, you will get Finder Menu Bar almost every time you try to use Menu Bar. Because Finder runs the Desktop. And almost always cannot reach Menu Bar without going pass Desktop. Sigh.

Comment: This is stupid, as is the whole "1 menu bar on top for everything" idea.
Thanks for your explanations!

Comment: 1st question: The app should go to the screen you clicked because it will be the screen that have the focus (you clicked in it). 2nd question: answered with the first question. Even Unity(Free) has this feature.

Comment: The Mac OS has never, including Classic Mac OS, had the menu bar anywhere but at the top of the screen. The Dock came decades later when OS X was released.